# How does Thought Sponge interact with Yarok, the Desecrated?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

### Situation

I have [Yarok, the Desecrated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYarok%2c%20the%20Desecrated%5d) on the battlefield:

> If a permanent entering the battlefield causes a triggered ability of a permanent you control to trigger, that ability triggers an additional time.

I play [Thought Sponge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThought%20Sponge%5d), after my opponent drew three cards this turn:

> Thought Sponge enters the battlefield with a number of +1/+1 counters on it equal to the greatest number of cards an opponent has drawn this turn.

Does this creature's triggered ability trigger an additional time? Is it entering as a 4/4, or as a 7/7?

### Confusion

I'm not sure whether this effect counts as replacement effect, as mentioned in the rulings of Yarok:

> *7/12/2019.* Replacement effects are unaffected by Yarok’s ability. For example, a creature that enters the battlefield with one +1/+1 counter on it won’t receive an additional +1/+1 counter.

Comment: That is not a triggered ability. *113.3c Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[Trigger condition], [effect],” and include (and usually begin with) the word “when,” “whenever,” or “at.” [...]*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, Thought Sponge won't trigger again. In fact, it doesn't even trigger at all, since it is indeed a replacement effect:

> 614.1c Effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield with . . . ,” “As [this permanent] enters the battlefield . . . ,” or “[This permanent] enters the battlefield as . . . “ are replacement effects.

and as you noted, replacement effects are unaffected by Yarok's ability.

A similar card which *is* affected by Yarok is [Propeller Pioneer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPropeller%20Pioneer%5d) which has the Fabricate 1 ability:

> When this creature enters the battlefield, put a +1/+1 counter on it or create a 1/1 colorless Servo artifact creature token.

This is a triggered ability:

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

Comment: Might be worth stating that if Thought Sponge's wording was "When Thought Sponge Enters the Battlefield, put a number of +1/+1 counters on it...", that would be a triggered ability and would be doubled.

Additionally, if there was a card like Doubling Season or Corpsejack Menace on your board, the number of counters would be doubled.

Comment: @Soulus101 any examples of those cards? (When ... enters the battlefield, put X +1/+1 counters on it...") My gut feeling says Wizards wouldn't print them, because they would be so similar yet different.

Comment: It's more to a point of "this is what a triggered ability would look like", rather than "and this exists". However, as it happens, the "Fabricate" mechanic from Aether Revolt does this (sort of), and similar effects exist.

Comment: @Glorfindel cards like that are rare for another reason, most of the cards that enter with +1/+1 counters based on something in the game state are base 0/0, and would die before the counters were added as SBA if it was a triggered ability rather than a replacement effect.

Answer (score 1):

While Glorfindel has already [answered](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/49846/25333) this question, the rulings on Gatherer reinforce that Thought Sponge's effect is a replacement effect:

> Thought Sponge gets its +1/+1 counters at the moment it enters the
>   battlefield. There’s not a time that it’s on the battlefield before
>   its replacement effect has applied.